# Permission missing for creating Notes in Lightning Experience

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-experience, permissions, notes

I have a custom link to redirect the user to create a new note. 
In Salesforce classic, the custom link works and the user is able to create a note. When I switch to Lightning Experience and click the same custom link, I receive the following error message.

> Looks like there's a problem.
>
> You do not have permission to execute that operation.

I am using the same user in both Classic and in Lightning Experience. The issue is only occurring in Lightning Experience.

[image]

Comment: In Lightning, you can not insert old note. You can only insert Enhanced note. If you have noticed, notes and attachment related list do not have the new note option. The object is called Content Note. I would like you to edit your question with link you are using.